# Executing code before main()

Tags: c

In object-oriented languages (C++) you can execute code before `main()` by using a global object or a class static object and have their constructors run the code you want.

Is there any way to do this in C? I don't have any specific problem I'm trying to solve, I'm just curious. One thing this might be useful for is automatically initializing a library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949890/how-can-i-perform-pre-main-initialization-in-c-c-with-avr-gcc

Comment: @stacker - The question you refer to is specific to Arduino environment. Anyway, answers there may be helpful.

Comment: Not in any standards-compliant way, but you should dig in to what really happens when your operating system loads the binary image and calls the application main function!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are ways using `__attribute__` but those are very specific to your compiler and code that is written using these are **not** really portable. On the other hand, the C language does not provide any start-up modules/libraries.

In C, logically `main()` is the first function called by the OS. But before calling `main()`, the OS calls another function called `start-up` module to setup various environment variables, initialize (un-initialized) static variables, build a stack frame (activation record) and initialize the stack pointer to the start of the stack area and other tasks that have to be done before calling `main()`.

Say if you are writing code for embedded systems where there is no-or-minimal OS to do the above mentioned work, then you should explore these options which are compiler dependent. Other than GCC, Turbo-C and Microsoft C compilers provides facilities to add code in a particular hardware machine (f.e. 8086 machines).

In other words, the start-up modules are not meant for the programmers.

Comment: Wrong, `main` is not the first function called by the OS. Have you heard of [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0)? `_start` is always called before `main`, and in Windows, `WinMain` is called before `main` also.

Comment: This is False! _start is called by the OS. _start generally (based on your compiler) will call __libc_start_main, which will call main.

Answer (score 32):

You can do it with `__attribute__ ((constructor))`. I've tested the following example with both `gcc` and `clang`. That being said, it's **not** part of the language.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void __attribute__ ((constructor)) premain()
{
    printf("premain()\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("main()\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It does the following:

```
$ ./test
premain()
main()
```

GCC documents it at: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.3.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes

Answer (score 6):

With gcc, you can do so by using the constructor function attribute, e.g.

```
__attribute__ ((__constructor__)) 
void foo(void) {
        ...
}
```

This will invoke foo before main.

Note: This is probably not portable to other compilers.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler can compile cpp files you can add a file with a class that call in the costructor your initialization code. The class must be allocated statically. For example:

```
#include "ext.h"

class cext
{
public:
   cext()
   {
      ExtInit();
   }

   ~cext(){};
};

cext g_cext;
```

The ExtInit() function must be defined as extern "C" in file ext.h.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
void   ExtInit   (void);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: And this drags in the entire C++ runtime library, and ties anyone who want to use the code to that one specific C++ runtime.  There's a reason why the question was tagged C and not C++.

Comment: It’s still potentially useful so I’m glad it’s here, I might use this. Also can’t you do this without the standard library? Or is the runtime library a different thing? I know of libgcc but that’s used for C too

Answer (score -1):

You can initialize global variables but not call functions within these initializations.